# Is Sys.time() the time required for the individual computer to run commands?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, time

I am using the R programming language. I am learning about different types of "times" in computing. There seems to be two types of general times : the time corresponding to the general mathematical complexity of the procedures you are running, and the time corresponding to how long it takes your individual computer to run the procedures.

I came across the Sys.time() command in R over here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/05/5-ways-to-measure-running-time-of-r-code/

Does Sys.time() measure the time required for your individual computer to run the commands? For example, I  wrote the code below using Sys.time() to measure the time it takes my personal computer to run the following procedure in R for different numbers of observations.

```
 library(Rtsne)
    library(cluster)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(dplyr)
    library(dbscan)
    library(plotly)


#generate data

var_1 <- rnorm(1000,1,4)
var_2<-rnorm(1000,10,5)
var_3 <- sample( LETTERS[1:4], 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.1, 0.2, 0.65, 0.05) )
response_variable <- sample( LETTERS[1:2], 100, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6) )


#put them into a data frame called "f"
f <- data.frame(var_1, var_2, var_3, response_variable)

#declare var_3 and response_variable as factors
f$response_variable = as.factor(f$response_variable)
f$var_3 = as.factor(f$var_3)

#create id
f$ID <- seq_along(f[,1])


mseDF <- NULL

for (size in c(100,500,1000)) {
   
    start_time <- Sys.time()
   
   
    #gower distance
   
    gower_dist <- daisy(f[1:size, 1:4],
                        metric = "gower")
   
    lof <- lof(gower_dist, k=3)
   
    tsne_obj <- Rtsne(gower_dist,  is_distance = TRUE)
   
    tsne_data <- tsne_obj$Y %>%
        data.frame() %>%
        setNames(c("X", "Y")) %>%
        mutate(
            name = f[1:size,]$ID,
            lof=lof,
            var1=f[1:size,]$var_1,
            var2=f[1:size,]$var_2,
            var3=f[1:size,]$var_3
        )
   
    p1 <- ggplot(aes(x = X, y = Y, size=lof, key=name, var1=var1,
                     var2=var2, var3=var3), data = tsne_data) +
        geom_point(shape=1, col="red")+
        theme_minimal()
   
   
    ggplotly(p1, tooltip = c("lof", "name", "var1", "var2", "var3"))
    end_time <- Sys.time()
   
   (final = end_time - start_time)
   print (final)
mseDF <- rbind(mseDF, data.frame(size, final))

}
```

Is this correct?

Extra: visualize the run times:

```
plot(mseDF)
 lines(mseDF)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to use proc.time; e.g.

```
> start_time <- proc.time()
> # some computation
> for (i in 1:10000000) i ^ 3
> proc.time() - start_time
   user  system elapsed 
   0.70    0.02    0.72
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does Sys.time() measure the time required for your individual computer to run the commands?

No. `Sys.time()` returns the current time. Similarly `Sys.Date()` returns the current date. You could create an elapsed time function that has code in it by subtracting two calls to `Sys.time`. But your code implies that you already know how to do that, so perhaps English is not your first language and that question was a simple error in expression. So maybe "yes", since it appears you would get the elapsed time for a result to appear.

You might want to look at `?system.time`

```
system.time({for(i in 1:10e6){x <- Sys.time()}})
#   user  system elapsed 
# 13.274   0.000  13.273
```

There are also several benchmark packages (as demonstrated in that blog citation above.). Example: pkg:microbenchmark